# How do custom skins work in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In TF2, my friend subscribed to a skin pack for scout to become femscout. The person tried loading the game, but the game was not changed. How would my friend cause the changes to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add items from the Workshop to your game unless Valve adds them to the game. Wherever you subscribed to this item, it must have been outside the official TF2 Workshop, which is located at http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=440.

The only way to play with those models would be to set up an own Server and load those models into the game. More Information about that can be found [here](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User_modifications).